# jQuery Mobile - List with collapsible content

Tags: jquery, list, hide, show, expand

I'm trying to make a list where some entries can be clicked to expand/show more/hide. It's very similar to a `collapsible`, but some items have "extra info" and others don't. Also, it should be more on the "list" side, semantically. I've tried searching for "collapsible list item" but I come up with more "lists inside collapsibles".

Comment: try jquery mobile accordion like http://the-jquerymobile-tutorial.org/jquery-mobile-tutorial-CH20.php

Comment: @SathyaRaj that's the same as the jQuery mobile collapsible... and as I said it should be more "list" and less "container". I need a list of items, some of which can be expanded for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a normal list view like this for the items that **do not** need to expand or collapse.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b">
<li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then for the items that **do** use a collapsable list such as

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
   <h3>Stock #3 Order #3</h3>
   <ul data-role="listview">
   <li>Info 1</li>
   <li>Info 2</li>
   <li>Info 3</li>
   </ul>

   </div>
```